# Removing elements containing any alphabetical characters from list in R

Tags: r

I have the list with the following elements:

```
c("1",  "2", "3", "abc",  "1as")
```

How would I be able to remove elements that contains alphabets from the list? For instance, for the example above, I would wish to get ("1" "2" "3") as the final list, but 1,2,3 are all string variables in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how

```
a <- c("1",  "2", "3", "abc",  "1as")
a[!grepl("[[:alpha:]]", a)]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using `grep` to identify the entries with [[:alpha:]](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) entries and negating them:

```r
x <- c("1",  "2", "3", "abc", "1as")

x[-grep("[:alpha:]", x)]
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I recently discovered the `invert` argument in `grep` - you can also write `grep("[:alpha:]", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

A little longer, but you don't need to use grep to solve the problem.
You could simply convert, and those that are converted (not NA) are the ones you want to keep:

```
test<-c("1","2","3","abc","1as")
test_num<-as.numeric(test)
test_num_clean<-test_num[!is.na(test_num)]
```

And if you prefer strings:

```
test_str<-as.character(test_num_clean)
```